# Google: Disabling the appliance-hosted search page?

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is there a way to disable or password-protect the search page hosted on a Google Mini appliance? I'm referring to the page descriped in option 1 [here](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/46/help_mini/home_quickstart.html#basic_make).

I basically want to prevent someone from stumbling onto this URL and searching here rather than through one of the actual sites using the appliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some of these:

- delete the default front end
- delete the default collection
- set the Follow and Crawl URLs for the default collection to blank
- edit the XSLT stylesheet under Serving > Front Ends > Output format.

My experience is with the Google Search Applicance, so I hope this works on the Mini too.